# Apply regex replace only within "scope"

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I apply regex only within a certain scope, like between two `**`'s?

I want to use JavaScript to change this

```
**
    _a_ _b_ _c_
    -d- -e- -f-
**
_a_
```

into this

```
**
    {a} {b} {c}
    (d) (e) (f)
**
_a_
```

Notice that the desired result is that `_a_` is not changed outside of the "scope".

I can do this much

```
str
    .replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "{$1}")
    .replace(/-(.*?)-/g, "($1)")
```

but this will replace everywhere, even outside of the two `**`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this and it's simpler for me is to extract the string inside your delimiter `**`, and replace it with your existing regexes (which already works).

**E.g.**

```js
var str = `**
    _a_ _b_ _c_
    -d- -e- -f-
**
_a_`;

var result = str.replace(/\*\*(\s|.)+\*\*/g, function (x) {
 return x
           .replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "{$1}")
           .replace(/-(.*?)-/g, "($1)");
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea `.replace()`'s second parameter could be a function. This makes everything easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same or an simular solution as @choz does:

```js
var str = "_a_\n**_a_ _b_ _c_\n-d- -e- -f-** \n_a_ \n**_a_ _b_ _c_-d- -e- -f-**_a_";

// split into parts
var parts = str.split(/(\*\*)/);

var shouldReplace = false;
var buffer = "";


// go tough all values
parts.forEach((value) => {

  // negate shouldReplace if delimter
  if (value === "**") {
    buffer += value;
    shouldReplace = !shouldReplace;
    return;
  }

  // if not shouldReplace add to buffer
  if (!shouldReplace) {
    buffer += value;
    return;
  }

  // replace the value if shouldReplace
  buffer += value
              .replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "{$1}")
              .replace(/-(.*?)-/g, "($1)")
});

console.log(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was important to me to be able to make scoping with single regular expression. So it actually possible, thanks to [lookbehind](https://v8.dev/blog/regexp-lookbehind-assertions).

```js
var str = `**
    _a_ _b_ _c_
    -d- -e- -f-
**
_a_`;


var pattern1 = /(\*\*((?<!\*\*).|\n)*?)_(.*?)_((.|\n)*?\*\*)/g;
var pattern2 = /(\*\*((?<!\*\*).|\n)*?)-(.*?)-((.|\n)*?\*\*)/g;

var result = str;

while(result.match(pattern1) != null)
{
    result = result.replace(pattern1, "$1{$3}$4");
}
while(result.match(pattern2) != null)
{
    result = result.replace(pattern2, "$1($3)$4");
}

console.log(result);
```